# Can I handle an "undefined" case in a switch statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

If I'm passing an object to a case statement, and there is a case where it is undefined, can I handle that case? If so then how? If its not possible, then what is the best practice for handling an undefined case for a switch?

Comment: Why wouldn't `default` work in this case?

Comment: I actually never heard of MDN. Thanks for that. It will be useful for future JS questions.

Comment: I have, I just didnt think it would work with an "undeclared" value, and I wanted to see if anyone here would know. But apparently, undefined has 2 different meanings in the JS world, one which works in a case statement, and one which breaks it at runtime. Not so intuitive..

Comment: Is there a more "functional" version of a switch statement?

Comment: no, there's `typeof var == 'undefined'` and `var === undefined` and `var == undefined`, all of which have explicit meanings.

Comment: okay, so there is one additional meaning I did not know of...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Add a `case` for `undefined`.

```
case undefined:
  // code
  break;
```

Or, if all other options are exhausted, use the `default`.

```
default:
  // code
  break;
```

**Note:** To avoid errors, the variable supplied to `switch` has to be *declared* but can have an `undefined` value. Reference this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4GpY/) and read more about [defined and undefined variables in JavaScript](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript-help/javascript-testing-defined-undefined-variables.htm).

Comment: I think this answers my question. I just was not entirely sure if undefined would cause unexpected behavoir in a switch statement. Thanks!

Comment: Your last updated confuses me. What if it is undefined, and it is not defined anywhere? I just tested out the code and yeah, it breaks at runtime due to the argument being undefined.

Comment: Again, the variable has to be *declared*, i.e. `var myvar`. Otherwise, you'll get an error.

Comment: @user1274649: You should be declaring variables before you use them. Are these global variables you're testing?

Comment: No, I'm using a framework which combines knockout and YUI and when I initialize a widget, I set all of its local variables to the bindings. If the binding isn't specified by the View, then it gets set to an undefined, undeclared value. I want to use a switch statement which handles all the cases for the posibilities for the binding, and also provides the default case if no binding is specidied.

Comment: You know `undefined` *can* be assigned a value right? I mean it *is* javascript after all ;-)

Comment: Ha, yes I do know that, but since this framework is going to be Open sourced at some point, I don't think that'd be the smartest thing to do...:)

Comment: I think you have two separate questions here. The one that was asked, and now a higher question regarding your framework design.

Comment: What, is there something I'm missing? When I jumped into JS a few weeks ago, I thought redefining undefined was a quirky AWFUL thing about JS that you want to avoid at all costs...i dont see why anyone would put their hands on the language like that. It seems dangerous.

Comment: It seems the standard.js linter does not like this usage: `Parsing error: The keyword 'undefined' is reserved`

Answer (score 4):

Well, the most portable way would be to define a new variable `undefined` in your closure, that way you can completely avoid the case when someone does `undefined = 1;` somewhere in the code base (as a global var), which would completely bork most of the implementations here.

```
(function() {
    var foo;
    var undefined;

    switch (foo) {
        case 1:
            //something
            break;
        case 2:
            //something
            break;
        case undefined:
            // Something else!
            break;
        default:
            // Default condition
    }
})();
```

By explicitly declaring the variable, you prevent integration issues where you depend upon the global state of the `undefined` variable...

Comment: Downvoter: any comment as to the rationale for the downvote? Can this answer be improved? Is there a fundamental issue that you disagree with? Something worth discussing at least?

Answer (score 3):

If you're comparing object references, but the variable may not be assigned a value, it'll work like any other case to simply use `undefined`.

```
var obs = [
    {},
    {}
];

var ob = obs[~~(Math.random() * (obs.length + 1))];

switch(ob) {
    case obs[0]: 
        alert(0); 
        break;
    case obs[1]:
        alert(1); 
        break;
    case undefined: 
        alert("Undefined"); 
        break;
    default: alert("some unknown value");
}
```

Comment: Thansk @jcolebrand. I didn't consider that I had excluded `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `undefined` really is just another *value* (`'undefined' in window === true`), you can check for that.

```
var foo;

switch( foo ) {
    case 1:
        console.log('1');
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('2');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('3');
        break;
    case undefined:
        console.log('undefined');
        break;
}
```

works just about right.